# Locales/literals containing html

Tags: html, vue.js, translation, nuxt.js

In

`locale/lang.json` I have

```
{
  "title": "Title",
  "image": "service-corporate_thumb-v2.jpg",
  "alt": "alt",
  "imageFooter": "Some caption %",
  "imageFooterCTA": "author",
  "imageFooterURL": "https://example.com/author",
},
```

I'm trying to generate the author like, like so:

```
<img :src="require(`~/assets/img/services/${service.image}`)" :alt="service.alt" class="mb-8">
<p>{{ service.imageFooter.replace('%', `<a href="${service.imageFooterURL}" target="_blank" class="primary-text">${service.imageFooterCTA}</a>`) }}</p>
```

But this prints out in the generated HTML:

```
{{ service.imageFooter.replace('%', `${service.imageFooterCTA}`) }}
```

How can I generate html inside the {{ expresion }} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use v-html for generating html in a template.

More info [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML).

For your example try this

```
<p class="mb-8">
 <a v-html="service.imageFooter.replace('%', '<a href="$' + service.imageFooterURL + '" target="_blank" class="primary-text">$' + service.imageFooterCTA + '</a>')">
</p>
```

Notes:

- the tag that has a `v-html` directive will be replaced, so you could use anything, not only `a`
- the value for `v-html` needs to be valid JS code that will be executed in the current context. This the reason I treated the tag inside as a string and removed the interpolation `{`.

Comment: Thanks! so how would be for my example? documentation is very short and with just one very simple example

Comment: Thanks but note that you are changing the string concatenating $, this is how i did it: https://jsfiddle.net/vt21f850/ ( fiddle to prevent the code formatting )